# Keep scroll position when adding element to the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to create a calendar that can be infinitely scrolled to the left and to the right. It has to load new content dynamically as the user scrolls forward (easy) or backward (the problem is here).

When I add content to the end of the page, it works fine - the scrollbar adjusts to the new `container.scrollWidth`. But when I have to add content to the start, the whole calendar moves to the right in a huge 400px jump, because the `container.scrollLeft` property hasn't changed and there's now a new element at the start.

I'm trying to mitigate this by increasing the `container.scrollLeft` by 400px - width of the newly created element. This approach works, but only when scrolling with mousewheel (shift+mousewheel to scroll sideways) or mobile touchscreen.

If I use my mouse to drag the scrollbar, it kind of glitches out - my guess is it keeps trying to scroll to the old `scrollLeft` position and disregards that I increased it.

Could you please suggest a way to achieve this behavior for all ways of scrolling?

It would also be great if you could just point me to a site that uses this technique so I could investigate myself.

Here's my semi-working example:

```js
function Container() {
  const rectangleWidth = 400;

  const container = React.useRef(null);

  const [leftRectangles, setLeftRectangles] = React.useState([0]);
  const [rightRectangles, setRightRectangles] = React.useState([1, 2, 3, 4]);


    // When we just rendered a new rectangle in the left of our container,
  // move the scroll position back
  React.useEffect(() => {
    container.current.scrollLeft += rectangleWidth;
  }, [leftRectangles]);

  const loadLeftRectangle = () => {
    const newAddress = leftRectangles[0] - 1;
    setLeftRectangles([newAddress, ...leftRectangles]);
  };

  const loadRightRectangle = () => {
    const newAddress = rightRectangles[rightRectangles.length - 1] + 1;
    setRightRectangles([...rightRectangles, newAddress]);
  };

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    // When there is only 100px of content left, load new content
    const loadingOffset = 100;
    
    if (e.target.scrollLeft < loadingOffset) {
      loadLeftRectangle(e.target);
    } else if (e.target.scrollLeft > e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.clientWidth - loadingOffset) {
      loadRightRectangle(e.target);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      ref={container}
    >
      {leftRectangles.map((address) => (
        <div className="rectangle" key={address}>
          {address}
        </div>
      ))}
      {rightRectangles.map((address) => (
        <div className="rectangle" key={address}>
          {address}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 165px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 165px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a case where one should not use native browser scroll areas. If you think about it, scrollbars have no meaning if they continue to get longer infinitely in both directions. Or their only meaning is "area which has been viewed". A scrollbar is not a good metaphor for an infinite area, and therefore a scrollbox is a poor way to do what you want to do here.

If you think of it another way, you are only showing a set of months which fit within a known screen width. The way I would approach this would be to absolute position each calendar inside a container and calculate their positions in a render loop based on where in a virtual view the user is shuttling. This also would allow you to remove calendars once they go too far off screen and create/buffer them offscreen for display before the user scrolls to their position. It would prevent you from having an arbitrarily wide object which would eventually slow down rendering.

One approach to this would be to simply number each month since 1970 and treat your view as having a fractional position `viewX` along this line. The month for `x` should have a position of `viewX - x`. When the user is dragging you move `viewX` inversely and reposition the buffered elements. When the user stops dragging, you take the last velocity and slow it until `viewX - x` is an integer.

This would avoid most cross-browser issues and offset problems. It only requires a render loop while the display is in motion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like the idea of completely avoiding native scrollers. I am kind of scared of implementing my own scrolling - I should be able to handle mousewheel and touchscreen alike. I have another concern - the calendar will have to be also scrolled vertically on small screens. I will explore this option tomorrow, since I'm going to sleep, and I will keep you updated.

Comment: Sure! One thing you might consider is using a transparent scroll area over your graphics to capture the user input. This would save you from needing to write your own mouse wheel and touch input handlers. You would take the scroll event from the hidden box and check its new scroll position versus its last one, and use the difference to offset your virtual scroll. This can also help you control the speed. The box doesn't need to be very large... it can jump to the top over and over and you can calculate `y % scrollboxHeight`... the purpose is to know the amount it moved, not an actual position.

Comment: This answer is great, perhaps something like [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) can help.

Comment: [react-infinite-calendar](https://github.com/clauderic/react-infinite-calendar) looks like what you're trying to do, using react virtualized

Comment: I tried the transparent scroll area, but I couldn't manage to get it working properly - the scrollbar size has to either match the size of the loaded content, then detaching it becomes pointless), or it's fixed and I have to reset it to the center, which kinda worked, but the movement was super jerky.

Comment: However, the original issue with scrolling back was resolved by adding a loading time of 1 second + allowing only 1 week to be loaded at a time (this resolved instantly scrolling through 10s of weeks).

Comment: Since your solution (rendering with position: fixed) actually allowed to completely solve my issue too (I could have easily added scroll with react-draggable to make it work), I will give the bounty to your answer.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov Cheers! Glad you solved it. From your description, I would be interested to see the final product.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `read-write` `scrollLeft` to get the scroll position prior to dynamically adding content then use the `.scrollLeft` method to reposition the scroll position back to where you want it. You might need fire off a *dialog* displaying an *indeterminant progress indicator* ( or simply display text "working..." ) which displays during the process to prevent *janking*.

The trick for cross browser functionality is that `dialog` element which is well known to be challenging regarding consistency across device types so I would recommend using a UI library for your dialog or build your own but keep it super simple. That progress indicator will be the fix for screen jank.

Another feature to consider regarding janking would be [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) where the addition of content (e.g. a block element) would gradually fade/animate in to the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it's 11:56 PM in my timezone, and I'm going to sleep. I will try to make a working solution based on your answer first thing in the morning. I will keep you updated on my progress.